# html select option apply javascript function to div

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating HTML select dropdown (font-size). When I am selecting the value from the dropdown for example h1.

Under the dropdown I have the text which i need to apply h1.

I was trying to  creating css class for all the heading tag from H1 - h6 and in the onClick of every option apply css using add and remove.

```
<select>
    <option>h1</option>
    <option>h2</option>
    <option>h3</option>
</select>
<div id="text">
    Text
</div>
```

But I don't now how to do that.  [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/gfwbke1h/)

Kindly help me how to

Comment: are you using any libraries ( e.g. jquery? ) or you want it in pure javascript?

Comment: actually I was tyring in  pure javascript

Answer (score 6):

You need to listen `onchange` event on select element, and based on the selected value apply corresponding class to the div.

One possible implementation:

```js
// Get select element
var select = document.querySelector('select');

// Bind onchange event
select.onchange = function() {
    document.querySelector('#text').className = this.value;
};

// Trigger event to apply initial value
select.onchange();
```

```css
.h1 {font-size: 32px;}
.h2 {font-size: 24px;}
.h3 {font-size: 19px;}
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="h1">h1</option>
    <option value="h2">h2</option>
    <option value="h3">h3</option>
</select>

<div id="text">Text</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much but is that possible in pure javscaript I guess this was Jquery right

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `addEventListener` method instead of the `onchange` property because it is considered more flexible and is part of the DOM Events specification. So, this can be considered better practice. Using properties like `onchange` restricts you by only allowing you to assign one event handler at a time for the target element.

Below is a solution using JavaScript to add the `change` event listener to the element versus modifying the property of the element itself.

```js
(function changeListener() {
  var select = document.querySelector('select'),
      text = document.getElementById('text');

  // add change listener
  select.addEventListener('change', function () {
    text.className = this.value;
  });

  // default size
  text.className = select.value;
}());
```

```css
.h1 { font-size: 32px; }
.h2 { font-size: 24px; }
.h3 { font-size: 19px; }
```

```html
<select>
    <option>h1</option>
    <option>h2</option>
    <option>h3</option>
</select>
<div id="text">
    Text
</div>
```